# Is there a Django ManyToManyField with implied ownership?

Tags: django, django-models, database-design, data-modeling

Let's imagine I'm building a Django site "CartoonWiki" which allows users to write wiki articles (represented by the `WikiArticle`-model) as well as posting in a forum (represented by the `ForumPost`-model). Over time more features will be added to the site.

A `WikiArticle` has a number of `FileUpload`s which should be deleted when the `WikiArticle` is deleted. By "deleted" I mean Django's `.delete()`-method.

However, the `FileUpload`-model is generic -- it's not specific to `WikiArticle` -- and contains generic file upload logic that e.g. removes the file from S3 when it's removed from the database. Other models like `ForumPost` will use the `FileUpload`-model as well.

I don't want to use `GenericForeignKey` nor multi-table inheritance for the reasons Luke Plant states in the blog post [Avoid Django's GenericForeignKey](https://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/avoid-django-genericforeignkey/). (However, if you can convince me that there really is no better way than the trade-offs `GenericForeignKey` make, I might be swayed and accept a convincing answer of that sort.)

Now, the most trivial way to do this is to have:

```py
class FileUpload(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey('WikiArticle', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey('ForumPost', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

But that will have the `FileUpload`-model expand indefinitely with more fields -- and similar its underlying table will gain more and more columns as new models in the system start using `FileUpload`. This feels suboptimal both in terms of data-modeling, but also in terms of separation-of-concerns -- the `FileUpload`-model and table is being changed while no actual new functionality is being added to it.

My preference would really be to go the other way around:

```py
class WikiArticle(models.Model):
    uploads = models.ManyToManyField('FileUpload')
```

But this doesn't solve the deletion issue: If I `.delete()` a `WikiArticle` the corresponding `FileUpload`s won't be deleted. I've tried various setups with through-models, but none seem to solve it. What I really need is a `OneToMany`-field -- a sort of reverse `ForeignKey` to indicate the ownership in the right direction without polluting the generic/reusable model.

Should `FileUpload` really instead be a field? Or perhaps an abstract model? (`WikiArticleFileUpload`, `ForumPostFileUpload`, and so on...).

I realize that a true `ManyToManyField` with implied ownership would no longer really be a `ManyToManyField` since the field implies sharing. E.g. a `FileUpload` could technically be referenced by multiple `WikiArticle`s, so you could be removing `FileUploads` from other objects rather on top of the one you're deleting. The question still stands though -- it seems I need a `OneToManyField` to model this in a nice way.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a couple of options to solve your problem, but it also requires on the exact requirements of your application.

1. Using a `GenericForeignKey` in this situation is probably fine, escpecially due to the fact that you do not know how many other models will use your upload model. Of course as mentioned in the linked blog post eg. doing plain SQL queries might be harder but it's on you to decide if that's a problem for your use case.
2. Also using inheritance might be an option, so that all the referenced models inherit the relation to the upload model from a common ancestor. This might have a small impact performance-wise because you Django would need to join the tables of the models but the impact might still be not that big. On the other hand this approach might also have some advantages if eg. your articles and posts have other stuff in common as well and you could easily do stuff like "show all new posts and articles (together)".
3. If you handle deletion yourself as mentioned in the previous answer you can also add `ManyToMany` fields yourself but also consider that this method also has some disadvantages in common with using generic foreign keys (eg. a lot of stuff to join in the database...)

Probably it's fine that you just use a `GenericForeignKey`, especially if the number of models that use your "generic" model gets bigger (eg. more than 3-5). All in all this sounds pretty much like a use case `GenericForeignKey` was made for (imagine the uploads being something like "tags" belonging to the posts).

Answer (score 0):

`ManyToMany` fields are symmetrical, even though you define them on one model with an (explicit or implicit) related_name on the other.

I can think of two methods to clean up while, or after, `WikiArticle`s are deleted. The first is to periodically search for and delete "orphan" FileUploads. At its simplest, (assuming a related_name of `articles`)

```
deleted = FileUpload.objects.filter( articles__isnull=True).delete()
```

The other is to explicitly process the related articles during deleting of the article. It's straightforward to subclass the object's `delete` method, but this is not the only way to delete an object (bulk_delete, for example, bypasses this). Anyway,

```
def delete( self, *args, **kwargs):

    article_pks = self.uploads.all().values_list('pk', Flat=True)
    response = super().delete( *args, **kwargs)
    FileUpload.objects.filter( 
        pk__in = article_pks, articles__isnull=True) .delete()
    return response
```

(or even just execute the "periodically" code above, for every article-deletion, which will also tity after any deleted though othr channels)

Please *thoroughly* test this if you use it. Delete operations which don't do precisely what is wanted are the scariest sorts of bug!